# How do you authenticate a cookie from an old VB.Net site in an ASP.Net Core site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, authentication, asp.net-core

I need to use an authentication cookie created by an old VB.Net aspx project in my shiny new ASP.Net Core Web API + Angular2 project. I am very new to cookie based authorization and authentication and nobody in my company knows how to translate what they know to what I'm trying to do.

**Days of research and tinkering have gotten me this far:**
Right now I can set the [Authorize] attribute wherever needed and block access returning the usual 401 error but my site doesn't seem to recognize the cookie created by his site as the proverbial key for that lock...

> In **Startup.cs** - I'm not doing anything outside of the "**Configure()**" method, should I be?

I'm configuring the site to use cookie authentication, setting the scheme to "Cookies" without knowing exactly what that does and setting the "CookieName" to the name of the auth cookie created by login from that old site.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
          {
              // Stuff eliminated for brevity

              // Set up pipeline
              app.UseDefaultFiles();
              app.UseStaticFiles();
              //app.UseIdentity(); (Don't think I need this??)

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies", //(Dont actually know what this does. Should I create my own middlewares? I mean what is this magic string "Cookies"? It's just from tutorials/examples...)
                LoginPath = new PathString("/base_site/login.aspx"),
                AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/base_site/logon.aspx"), // Might want to create an error page...
                CookieName = "companyName_AccessLevel", //This is what he had in <forms name="companyName_AccessLevel">
                ReturnUrlParameter = "index.html", //What youd put in <forms defaultUrl="index.html">
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true

            });

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Frankly, this all seems awfully complicated compared to what my colleague suggested based on his asp.net experience:

> "Just put this in your **web.config**" he tells me

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="companyName_AccessLevel" loginUrl="/base_site/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" defaultUrl="index.html"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

So of course he's not too enthused about researching this "other way" with me. Can I somehow just revert to web.config?

Answer (score 1):

The cookies are encrypted, you must use a similar encryption technique and shared keys in order to read the cookies across 2 different sites. There is an Nuget package that will allow you to configure an old asp.net 4.x site to share cookies with core site. This is the official doc for it.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing.html?highlight=share%20cookie#sharing-authentication-cookies-between-asp-net-4-x-and-asp-net-core-applications

Answer (score 0):

> To configure forms authentication across applications, you set
>   attributes of the forms and machineKey sections of the Web.config file
>   to the same values for all applications that are participating in
>   shared forms authentication.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx